# Where does the function for os.walk onerror return to? How do I add more arguments to the onerror function call?

Tags: python, os.walk

Im writing a program to walk a filesystem using os.walk.

I have my for loop using os.walk, and onerror function as follows:

```
def walk_error(os_error):

    return(os_error)

def main():

    for root, dirs, files in os.walk('/var/spool/cron/', onerror=walk_error):

    print(root, dirs, files)
```

Where does that return statement from the `onerror` function go to? How do I reference it? I can certainly just do `print(os_error)` in my `walk_error` function and it will work fine.
But I want to save that error somewhere.

How do I, say, add a list as an argument to the error handling function aswell, so I can append that error to a list of my failed directories?

For example:

```
def walk_error(os_error, list_of_errors):
    list_of_errors.append(os_error)
```

That would work great! But unfortunately it doesnt seem you can do that type of a function call with multiple arguments in the `onerror` call.

Or how do I assign that returned value to a variable to do that in my main function? That os_error is being "returned" but its not returned to any of the 3 tuples that os.walk generates. Is there a way to reference that returned value in `main()`?

How do I do more complicated error handling here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the purpose of the return statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7129285/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-return-statement)

Comment: You could definitely do "that type of a function call" with a `functools.partial`, or even with a `lambda`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a `lambda` or a [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functools.html?highlight=partial) to implement your multiple-parameter `onerror` function.

```
def walk_error(os_error, list_of_errors):
    list_of_errors.append(os_error)

some_list = []

for root, dirs, files in os.walk("some/path", onerror=lambda err: walk_error(err, some_list):
    do_stuff()
```

or

```
import functools

...  # as above

for root, dirs, files in os.walk("some/path", onerror=functools.partial(walk_error, list_of_errors=some_list)):
    do_stuff()
```

Answer (score 3):

Use an inner function (aka closure):

```
def main():

    list_of_errors = []

    def walk_error(os_error):
        list_of_errors.append(os_error)

    for root, dirs, files in os.walk('/var/spool/cron/', onerror=walk_error):
        print(root, dirs, files)
```